# TimeSpan conversion from Custom Strings

Tags: c#, datetime

I've got a custom control on my page that has a field for Hours, Minutes, and AM/PM.  I need to be able to take each string Hour + Minutes + AM/PM and get a valid TimeSpan so I can combine with a Date.

I've tried a couple different ways but get Invalid TimeSpan errors.  Here is my code

```
 string date = DateDropDown.SelectedValue;
 string hour = HourDropDown.SelectedValue;
 string minute = MinuteDropDown.SelectedValue;
 string timeofDay = AMPMDropDown.SelectedValue;

 string timeStr = hour.PadLeft(2, '0') + ":" + minute + timeofDay;

 TimeSpan custTime = TimeSpan.Parse(timeStr);
 DateTime custDate = DateTime.Parse(date);
 DateTime callBackDT = custDate.Add(custTime);
```

Aside from considering errors with the Parse.  How can I get a valid timespan from with the time strings and am/pm?

Thanks

Comment: how the final string would look like ?

Comment: Keep in mind that a `TimeSpan` is meant to represent a measured duration of time.  It can be longer than a day, or can be negative.  It's funny that `DateTime.TimeOfDay` uses a `TimeSpan` type, because that isn't what it is meant for.  But hey, that's just the tip of the iceberg when it comes to .Net and `DateTime` screwyness.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just parse the `DateTime` once, at the end:

```
string date = DateDropDown.SelectedValue;
string hour = HourDropDown.SelectedValue;
string minute = MinuteDropDown.SelectedValue;
string timeofDay = AMPMDropDown.SelectedValue;

string dateStr = date + " " + hour.PadLeft(2, '0') + ":" + minute + " " + timeofDay;

DateTime callBackDT = DateTime.Parse(dateStr);
```

There is no reason to build a `TimeSpan` in this case, as `DateTime.Parse` can handle dates with times as a single `DateTime`.

Comment: I clearly tried to over complicate that.  Thanks for untangling my thoughts!

Answer (score 2):

If you don't have to use `TimeSpan`, just parse the entire string with [`DateTime.Parse`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/vstudio/kc8s65zs.aspx):

```
var timeStr = string.Format("{0} {1}:{2} {3}", date, hour.PadLeft(2, '0'), minute, timeofDay);
var callBackDT = DateTime.Parse(timeStr, CultureInfo.CreateSpecificCulture("en-US"));
// Or whatever culture your string will be formatted with
```

Answer (score 1):

`TimeSpan` objects don't have a concept of am / pm. You'd have to use a `DateTime` instead:

```
string timeStr = hour.PadLeft(2, '0') + ":" + minute.PadLeft(2, '0') + " " + timeofDay;
DateTime custDate = DateTime.ParseExact("HH:mm t", timeStr, null);
TimeSpan custTime = custDate.TimeOfDay;
```

**Further Reading**

- [Custom Date and Time Format Strings](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4.aspx)